# Triggering an Airflow DAG from terminal not working

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to use airflow to define a specific workflow that I want to manually trigger from the command line.

I create the DAG and add a bunch of tasks.

```
dag = airflow.DAG(
    "DAG_NAME",
    start_date=datetime(2015, 1, 1),
    schedule_interval=None,
    default_args=args)
```

I then run in the terminal

```
airflow trigger_dag DAG_NAME
```

and nothing happens. The scheduler is running in another thread. Any direction is much appreciated. Thank You

Comment: can you see your dag when u make a `airflow list_dags`?

Comment: Also make sure that the DAG itself is switched on in the UI.

Comment: By default, the DAGs are in the 'paused' state, you will have to unpause them before you can trigger a DAG.

To unpause a DAG from the CLI, `airflow unpause dag_id`.
To unpause a DAG from the Web UI, go to the Web UI and turn on the DAG.

Answer (score 38):

I just encountered the same issue.

Assuming you are able to see your dag in `airflow list_dags` or via the web server then:

Not only did I have to turn on the dag in the web UI, but I also had to  ensure that `airflow scheduler` was running as a separate process.

Once I had the scheduler running I was able to successfully execute my dag using `airflow trigger_dag <dag_id>`

My dag configuration is not significantly different from yours.  I also have `schedule_interval=None`

Comment: I recently encountered the same issue as the poster - switching the DAG on in the UI allowed me to trigger a manual run just fine. Thanks!

Comment: I had a similar issue trying to run one of the stock examples with `airflow trigger_dag`. In that case the missing bit was that even though the DAGs were loaded from the `example_dags` module they also have to be visible to the `scheduler` in the `DAGS_FOLDER` or it won't check them.

Comment: @Aa'Koshh I know it's old, but just to clarify that with the dag examples, they don't have to be in the DAGS_FOLDER. You just need to turn on the toggle from UI of the dag you want to trigger and it will work.

Answer (score 10):

You may have disabled the workflow.
To enable the workflow manually. Open up the airflow web server by

```
$ airflow webserver -p 8080
```

Go to http://localhost:8080 . You should see the list of all available dags with a toggle button on/off. By default everything is set to off. Search for your dag and toggle your workflow. Now try triggering the workflow from terminal. It should work now.

Comment: sitting like 5 hours searching why my scheduler is not working and then found the dag was off... thanks mate!

Answer (score 6):

first make sure your database connection string on the airflow is working, weather it be on postgres, sqlite(by default) or any other database. Then run the command

```
 airflow initdb
```

This command should not be showing any connection errors

Secondly make sure your webserver is running on a separate thread

```
airflow webserver
```

Then run your schdeuler on a different thread

```
airflow scheduler
```

Finally trigger your dag on a different thread after the scheduler is running

```
airflow trigger_dag dag_id
```

Also make sure the dag name and task are present in the dag and task list

```
airflow list_dags
airflow list_tasks dag_id
```

And if the dag is switched off in your UI then toggle it on.

Answer (score 1):

You should 'unpause' the drag you what to trigger. use `airflow unpause xxx_drag` and then `airflow trigger_dag xxx_drag` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

airflow trigger_dag -e <execution_date> <dag_id>

Comment: An explanation would make your answer much more helpful